# How to create Jira task from GitLab CI?

Tags: gitlab, jira, pipeline, gitlab-ci

I can't find nothing about creating jira tasks from gitlab ci 
I created them from Jenkins by this way:

```
 def epicIssueFields = [fields: [project          : [key: "$PROJECT_ABBR"],
                                description      : 'New JIRA Created from Jenkins.',
                                customfield_10007: "Это Epic Name - $BUILD_NUMBER", //epic name
                                customfield_10100: [id: '10100'],
                                summary          : "Лучшая тема в мире", //тема
                                issuetype        : [name: 'Epic']
]]
stage('Creating JIRA EPIC') {
    def epicIssue = jiraNewIssue issue: epicIssueFields, site: 'TEST_JIRA'
    EPIC_NUMBER = epicIssue.data.key
    echo EPIC_NUMBER
}
```

How can I do it from gitlab ci?Are there some specific commands for this intro GitLab

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there is no ready to use plugin or integration for gitlab ci and jira. You can do this setup by changing your .gitlab-ci.yml file and using jira's REST API.

1. Create another job in your stage in .gitlab-ci.yml file and make it run with condition: `when: on_failure`. 
   https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#when
2. Make api call using curl to create new issue on your jire project.
   https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/rest-apis/